# javascript: a data structure to represent package versions

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm writing some script which manipulates versions of the packages in package.json. The thing which I found painful is comparing versions. Now, I represent them as strings and have some special functions which compare them which looks silly.

For example: 
'3.1.1' and '3.1.11'

So, what is proper data structure to represent them in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing them as strings makes the most sense. It's a well-formatted string which a machine can easily parse as necessary (similar to JSON).

If you do a Google search for something like "JS compare semantic version" you'll find a few libraries that will parse strings before comparing them. Storing versions as strings seems to be the recommended data structure.

Answer (score 1):

> Version comparison is similar to IP address comparison. refer
>   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347696/whats-the-most-performant-way-to-do-simple-ip-address-comparisons) question on IP address comparisons.